# Number of imaginary roots of $3x^7-x^5+2x^3-7=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Finding the number of imaginary roots of the equation $3x^7-x^5+2x^3-7=0$ is

Let $f(x)=3x^7-x^5+2x^3-7$

Then using the discrete rule of sign

We have sign change from $+$ to $-$

And $-$ to $+$ and $+$ to $-$

So at most $3$ positive real roots

And $f(-x)=-3x^7+x^5-2x^3-7$

Then here sign change from $-$ to $+$ and $-$ to $-$

So at most $2$ negative roots

But I did not know how I find the  number of complex roots of the form $a + ib$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}, b \neq 0$.

Please have a look

Comment: You should clarify whether you mean "imaginary" or "non-real complex" i.e. roots of the form $ib$ vs. $a + ib$ with $a, b \in \mathbb R, b \ne 0$.

Comment: @dxiv roots of the form $a+ib$

Comment: You should edit that into the question, not as a comment. As to the question, it's a $7^{th}$ degree polynomial. Can all $7$ roots be (non-real) complex, and why or why not?

Comment: Just a minor quibble: You definitely mean "Descartes's Rule of Signs" instead of "Discrete Rule of Sign", do you? @PritiBisht

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, here is how I solved this. We have the equation
$$3x^7 - x^5 + 2x^3 - 7 = 0$$

So, let $f(x) = 3x^7 - x^5 + 2x^3 - 7$ and its derivative with respect to $x$ is $$f^{\prime}(x) = 21x^6 - 5x^4 + 6x^2$$
$$\implies f^{\prime}(x) = x^2 \cdot(21x^4 - 5x^2 + 6)$$

Consider the quartic factor $(21x^4 - 5x^2 + 6)$. If we write $t = x^2$, then it becomes $(21t^2 - 5t + 6)$. The discriminant of this quadratic expression is
$$
\begin{align}
D &=(-5)^2 - 4 \times 21 \times 6\\
&= 25 - 504\\
&= -479
\end{align}
$$

Since the discriminant is negative, and the coefficient of $t^2$ is $21$, a positive number, $(21t^2 - 5t + 6)$ is positive for all values of $t$. From this, we can conclude that $(21x^4 - 5x^2 + 6)$ is also positive for all values of $x$. So, $f^{\prime}(x) \geq 0 \ \forall \ x \in \mathbb{R} \implies f(x)$ is a strictly increasing function. I say strictly increasing because the derivative will become $0$ only at one discrete point and not over an interval. So, $f(x) = 0$ for only one value of $x$, which means it has only one real root and six complex roots.